# Is it a good practice to call [super defaultPropertyValues] from child class in Realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

My question refers not only to `+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues` method but others like `+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties`, `+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties` etc.

For instance:

```
//.h - file
@interface A : RLMObject
@property NSString propertyA;
@end

//.m - file 
@implementation A
+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
      return @{@"propertyA":@""};
}
@end
```

Than I define class B inherited form A

```
//.h - file
@interface B : A
@property NSString propertyB;
@end

//.m - file 
@implementation B
+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
   NSMutableDictionary *defaultValues = [[super  defaultPropertyValues]mutableCopy];
  [defaultValues setObject:@"" forKey:@"propertyB"];
  return defaultValues;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm.)*

If you're simply subclassing an `RLMObject`, then it's not necessary to call `super` on those class methods.

That being said, in your case, where you're subsequently subclassing a subclass of an `RLMObject`, then yes, that's a definitely a good way to ensure you're not breaking the functionality of the parent classes.

I'd personally consider it good practice in the respect that it means you're not creating redundant information in these methods (i.e., if you changed anything in class `A`, class `B` would be fine as-is). :)